# Java Collections.sort() excluding a range of characters

Tags: java, string, sorting, collections

I have a question regarding java Collections.sort(), I have 2 files that are generated by a system and I am trying to compare the two, the first thing I do is use java's Collections.sort() to rewrite both files so that they are sorted, but what I have found is that these files have a system generated number in position offset 7 to 18 and because of this the files never seem to match..  I have written a line by line filtered compare.

```
EEEDDDDR00002384800000000041929CAD...
EEEDDDDR00002384900000000041956CAD...
EEEDDDDR00002385000000000041938CAD...
EEEDDDDR00002385200000000041965CAD...
EEEDDDDR00002385700000000004198CAD...
EEEDDDDR00002385800000000004199CAD...
       ^--------^
System Generated and change the sort order.
```

Is there a way that the compactor in the `Collections.sort` and **ignore** this range, and possibly other ranges on a line?

Comment: make a custom comparator method or lambda.

Comment: write custom comparator and remove this range before comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a custom `Comparator` that compares a string with indexes 7-18 removed. Java 8's syntax for [`Comparator.compating`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) makes writing such comparators quite elegant:

```
List<String> files = ...;
Collections.sort(files, 
                 Comparator.comparing(s -> s.substring(0, 7) + s.substring(18)));
```

Comment: @KevinRauer what exactly do you mean? If you explain what exactly you're missing, I could add it to my answer.

Comment: the java 8 example is a little too new for me.. I need to add logic to test to see if I even need to remove the characters depending on the data being sent in, and may need to exclude more ranges on that line as well..